# How do boosts work on alliance quests on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

I understand how linked nodes work. They are purple arrows where one end is the source of the boost, and the other end where the arrow is pointing to is the receiver of the boost.

In the image below we can see a droid boosting Ultron (the big boss). If someone kills the droid, the boost is removed making it much easier to defeat Ultron.

What I don't understand is those orange circles around bosses. For example, in the image below Ultron also has an orange boost. What are those boosts? Who is the source? And is it possible to remove them?

[image: Boosts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 types of nodes, Linked Nodes, and Local Nodes.

A Linked node shows a Purple icon on the drone, with a triangle with small circles on the points. It also "links" to another location via the arrows.

A Local node shows as an orange icon - in your example on Ultron.

Both provide a boost to the target champion - in both cases here, Ultron.

You can knock out the linked nodes, you can't knock out the local nodes.